# how to test import Control.Monad.Except with Hunit?

Tags: haskell, hunit

How can I test `Control.Monad.Except` (both guard results) a function like:

```
foo :: Double -> Double -> Except String Double
foo x y
  | x < -10.0 = throwError "Invalid parameter"
  | otherwise = pure $ x + y
```

using `hunit`?

Comment: It seems like from what I have seen so far it is impossible to use hunit with a non-IO Monad.

Comment: an alternative to hunit?

Comment: I'm not sure. Is there a reason you are using Except? I would use `Maybe` instead here.

Comment: I have a more complex case, that is a shortest example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's pretty straightforward to write some functions which use [`runExcept`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/mtl-2.2.1/docs/Control-Monad-Except.html#v:runExcept) to execute an `Except` action and use [`~?=`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/HUnit-1.5.0.0/docs/Test-HUnit-Base.html#v:-126--63--61-) to check its results.

```
shouldThrow :: Eq e => Except e a -> e -> Test
m `shouldThrow` e = runExcept m ~?= Left e

shouldReturn :: Eq a => Except e a -> a -> Test
m `shouldReturn` x = runExcept m ~?= Right x
```

Example usage:

```
testFoo = TestList [
    foo -11 2 `shouldThrow` "Invalid parameter",
    foo 3 1 `shouldReturn` 4
    ]
```

Comment: thanks, I was already trying to use `runExcept` but I was getting some errors, and I wasn't sure was the right thing to do.